# A function body must be provided. Try adding a function body

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I wrote it myself because `statefulwidget` didn't automatically create the pattern and out of 7 different errors I just couldn't fix this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NaberMain extends StatefulWidget {
  NaberMain({Key key}) : super(key: key)

  // ignore: empty_constructor_bodies
  @override 
  _NaberMainState createState() => _NaberMainState();
}

class _NaberMainState extends State<NaberMain> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You have a missing semi-colon after `super(key: key)`. Add the semi-colon.

```
class NaberMain extends StatefulWidget {
  NaberMain({Key key}) : super(key: key); //This is the semi-colon.

  @override 
  _NaberMainState createState() => _NaberMainState();
}

class _NaberMainState extends State<NaberMain> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Check it, please! maybe you forget the semicolon ";" before the error.