# Flutter Hive - Dead Lock ! code needs an Adapter class to run. but that Adapter class will be creatd after i run the code succesfully, in terminal

Tags: database, flutter, hive, flutter-hive, offline-storage

im new to programming, and english is my 2nd language, so please bypass any mistakes.

The instructor ran the build command in Terminal of IDE:

1. `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`
   or if in above fails, he usually runs below command:
2. `flutter pub get && flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs web`

---

but when i do the same error messages are generated.

error message:
This builder requires Dart inputs without syntax errors.
A function body must be provided.

**Error Message in Terminal**

```
E:\android\meter_switch>flutter packages pub run build_runner build

[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 711ms

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph...
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 124ms

[INFO] Checking for updates since last build...
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 1.1s

[INFO] Running build...
[SEVERE] hive_generator:hive_generator on lib/bank_account.dart:

This builder requires Dart inputs without syntax errors.
However, package:meter_switch/bank_account.dart (or an existing part) contains the following errors.
bank_account.dart:8:3: A function body must be provided.

Try fixing the errors and re-running the build.

[INFO] Running build completed, took 1.4s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 91ms

[SEVERE] Failed after 1.5s
pub finished with exit code 1
```

[1. before terminal command image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q12Fu.png)

[2. my code - after terminal - RUN section showed this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdKuC.png)

[3. my code - after terminal command image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ5j1.png)

Comment: Can you include your `bank_account.dart`

Answer (score 0):

### Ok issue solved.
its same issue as : [A function body must be provided. Try adding a function body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65715276/a-function-body-must-be-provided-try-adding-a-function-body)

### the issue was "**A function body must be provided**."
I just had to put a semi-collan at the end, after writing out the constructor of a class.

the base of whole issue was that I was just Too sure that the issue would not be in that specific file. And the surity that i would never forget a semicolan meade me fall into this abyss of ignorance.
I had looked at the stackOverflow page (link given above), but i never tried it out.